# Quickbook SDK not able to add bill : This feature is not enabled or not available

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am trying to add bill in by QuickBooks company file of Qb Enterprise version 2020, and installed qBSDK13, but not able to add Bil, it is showing

> This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks.

is there anything I need to change in my preference setting of company file?

```
request = requestMsgSet.AppendBillAddRq();
```

Comment: Post your code and/or the qbXML request you're sending to QuickBooks. There are _many things_ that can cause this error (e.g. currencies, classes, a specific version of QuickBooks, etc.), but without seeing what you're doing we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Error code is 3250 ?? Then you need to set the permission to access the particular section of the QuickBooks to the plugin